# If one of the resistors becomes open circuited, what is the power

Tags: power, parallel

**Question: The total power in a parallel circuit with four resistors of equal value is 570W. If one of the resistors becomes open circuited, what is the power dissipated by each of the remaining resistors?**

My Attempt:

\$P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + P_4 = 570\$

\$P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + \frac{v^2}{R} = 570\$

Open circuit causes \$R-> \infty \$

\$P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + \frac{v^2}{\infty} = 570\$

\$P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + 0 = 570\$

\$3P = 570\$

\$P = 190\$

This is not the correct answer, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Insufficient information. Is the circuit powered by a constant voltage, a constant current or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

\$P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + \frac{v^2}{\infty} = 570\$

is not valid, because total power changes as there is less loads (resistors) in the circuit.

You can see this by calculating the equivalent resistance, in this case was \$\frac{R}{4}\$ and now is \$\frac{R}{3}\$, so the resistance is higher and decreases the power.

Actually each resistor in parallel is responsible for a part of the total power, so, before, you had:

\$P_1 = P_2 = P_3 = P_4 = \frac{570}{4} = 142,2\$

**So as long as voltage remains the same over the resistors, dissipated power will remain the same**.

Now you have only three resistors, so:

\$P_{total} = P_1 + P_2 + P_3 = 3*142,2 = 427,5\$